# Как можно повернуть название оси в qwt?

Tags: qt5

Как можно повернуть название оси в qwt ? Понял как можно менять шрифт, но как повернуть из документации на QWT не понял. Думал что можно повернуть с помощью QwtText но нет.

```
    QFont font;
font.setFamily("TimesNewRoman");
font.setPointSizeF(10);

QwtPlot *d_plot = new QwtPlot(NULL);
d_plot->setFont(font);
d_plot->setTitle(" "); // заголовок
d_plot->setCanvasBackground(Qt::white); // цвет фона
// Параметры осей координат
QwtText titleY;
titleY.setFont(font);
titleY.setText("В");
QwtText titleX;
titleX.setFont(font);
titleX.setText("А");

d_plot->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::yLeft  , titleY);
d_plot->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::xBottom, titleX);
```

[image: указал что хочу повернуть]

Comment: void QwtScaleDraw::setLabelRotation (  double  rotation  )  

   https://docs.huihoo.com/qwt/class_qwt_scale_draw.html#bf5881339fddde65a00c1dd391023320